# where to put enableHighAccuracy and other settings for geolocation

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, geolocation

I have the following code which gets the geo location and posts it, then displays a button in div.  This works on desktops but does not work in android a common issue as mentioned on this site.  Recommendations are to add

```
 {frequency:5000, maximumAge: 0, timeout: 100, enableHighAccuracy:true}
```

to the code below somewhere, I've tried a few places just stops it working, where do I put these values please?

```
function getCoordPosition() { 

if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
function (position) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{path('login_log_location')}}",
           data: {
            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            longitude: position.coords.longitude
        },
        success: function () {
            $("#divputinarea").html("{{path('login_log_yourarea')}}">
           <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary">
           Find </button>');
          }

           });   
       });
    }  

}
```

After advice below I tried the following, it works without the { maximumAge: 0,timeout: 100,enableHighAccuracy:true} if I add it I get error 'argument 2 of geolocation.getCurrentPosition not callable"

```
 function getCoordPosition() { 

  if (navigator.geolocation) {

  function getPosition(position) {

    $.post("{{path('login_log_location')}}",  {  
     latitude:position.coords.latitude,
     longitude:position.coords.longitude })
     .done(function(data)  {
     $("#divputinarea").html('<form method=post action="
{{path('login_log_yourarea')}}"><button class="btn btn-large   
btn-primary">Find your nearest matches</button>');

 });

      }

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getPosition, {  
maximumAge: 0,timeout: 100,enableHighAccuracy:true} ); 

  }  

  }

 </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [getCurrentPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation.getCurrentPosition) method takes three parameters: a success callback, an error callback and an object containing configuration parameters.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    successCallback,
    errorCallback,
    {frequency:5000, maximumAge: 0, timeout: 100, enableHighAccuracy:true} 
);
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CvSW4/).

**EDIT:** You can modify your code to define these three parameters.

```
function getPosition(position) {
    $.post("{{path('login_log_location')}}",  {  
     latitude:position.coords.latitude,
     longitude:position.coords.longitude })
     .done(function(data)  {
         $("#divputinarea").html('<form method=post action="
    {{path('login_log_yourarea')}}"><button class="btn btn-large   
    btn-primary">Find your nearest matches</button>');
     });
  }

function onError(positionError) {
    // error handling goes here
}

function getCoordPosition() { 
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(   
        getPosition, // success callback
        onError, // error callback
        {maximumAge: 0,timeout: 100,enableHighAccuracy:true} // extra params
    ); 
  }  
}
```

Comment: @Nanchi I'm sure your jsfiddle works, but I still can't find a way of making with my jquery code see above attempt